# comparing the variables of a struct

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, compare

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question. lets say we have the following

```
    typedef struct {
        char month[2];
        char day[2];
        char year[4];
    } dateT;

void dates(dateT* ptrDateList);   

int main()
{
    dateT* ptrList;
    scanf("%d", &n);//number of date entries 
    ptrList = malloc(n*sizeof(dateT));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        dates(&ptrList[i]);
}

void dates(dateT* ptrDateList);
{
    char inputMonth[2];
    char inputDay[2];
    char inputYear[4];
    scanf("%s",inputMonth);
    strcpy(ptrDateList->month,inputMonth);
    scanf("%s",inputDay);
    strcpy(ptrDateList->day,inputDay);
    scanf("%s",inputYear);
    strcpy(ptrDateList->year,inputYear);
}
```

how you compare the value of day in ptrList[2] with lets say the value of day in ptrList[5]

I know that if I did

```
dateT list2={5,10,2009};
dateT list5={7,10,2009};
```

I could do

```
list2.day == list5.day
```

but how would I do that with the arrays

Comment: does your code compile? is there any error you are getting?

Comment: This was just an example to try and get an idea of how it was done

Comment: update my suggestion -- running the code is the best way to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptrList[2].day == ptrList[5].day` would work if the type was say integer, but as you store the characters you might want to use `strcmp`, like so:

```
if ((strcmp(ptrList[2].day,ptrList[5].day) == 0) // same day
```

note that you need an extra character for the end of string sentinel `\0`, 
so it should be;

```
typedef struct {
        char month[3];
        char day[3];
        char year[5];
} dateT;
```

another issue is the way you handle input: can you be sure that the user will provide valid input? for instance you could use `scanf("%2s", string);` to input the day (of max. length two).

Comment: I'll give that a try thanks, I couldn't find any examples anywhere. possible because I didn't know what to look for.

Comment: you should probably parse the input and save the days etc as ints anyway

Comment: I agree this was just an example to clarify what I was asking, wasn't paying attention when I wrote it up. I used the array[].member in my code and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Here's pretty much what **jev** already explain. Just I thought I might as well post it, since it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
        char month[3];
        char day[3];
        char year[5];
    } dateT;

void dates(dateT* ptrDateList);   

int main()
{
    dateT* ptrList;
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter number of dates: "); 
    scanf("%d", &n);//number of date entries 
    ptrList = malloc(n*sizeof(dateT));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        dates(&ptrList[i]);
    if (n > 1) {
        if (!strcmp(ptrList[0].day,ptrList[1].day)) {
            printf("First two days match.\n");
        } else {
            printf("First two days don't match.\n");
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}

void dates(dateT* ptrDateList)
{
    char inputMonth[3];
    char inputDay[3];
    char inputYear[5];

    printf("Enter month: "); 
    scanf("%2s",inputMonth);
    inputMonth[2] = '\0';
    strcpy(ptrDateList->month,inputMonth);

    printf("Enter Day: "); 
    scanf("%2s",inputDay);
    inputDay[2] = '\0';
    strcpy(ptrDateList->day,inputDay);

    printf("Enter Year: "); 
    scanf("%4s",inputYear);
    inputYear[4] = '\0';
    strcpy(ptrDateList->year,inputYear);
}
```